# How to cache rendered controllers?

Tags: php, symfony

I would like cache rendered controllers.

I have project in Symfony 3 and I found it: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/http_cache/esi.html

I have:

```
framework:
    # ...
    esi: { enabled: true }
    fragments: { path: /_fragment }
```

And in controller:

```
public function infoAction($maxPerPage)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
    $info = $em->getRepository(Info::class)->find(1);
    $response = $this->render('info.html.twig', [info => $info]);
    $response->setSharedMaxAge(600);

    return $response;
}
```

And in templates:

```
{{ render_esi(controller('AppBundle:News:info')) }}
```

I don't have any errors, and all is showing good, but this is not cached... If I change the data in the database, they are immediately displayed on the page, and should not appear until 600 seconds have passed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `Varnish` or other cache gateway in front of your application:

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/http_cache/esi.html

> ... All of this happens transparently at the gateway cache level (i.e. **outside of your application**).
>
> ... if you use the esi renderer (i.e. call render_esi()) and if Symfony detects that it's talking to a gateway cache that supports ESI, it generates an ESI include tag. But **if there is no gateway cache or if it does not support ESI, Symfony will just merge the included page content within the main one** as it would have done if you had used render().

Comment: Thanks, but maybe is simpliest way to cache controllers?